# Include variable names in estout along with factor variable values

Tags: stata

I'm trying to get `estout` to output the variable name along with the labels for individual values. For instance I have a variable labeled `AgeGroup` with values 0-9, 10-19, etc. `estout` only includes the label values.

For instance:
`eststo: logistic DepVar i.AGEGROUP i.RACE
estout est1 using regress_M.txt,label`

My output is:

```
DepVarLabel
1_AgeGroup Value label
2_AgeGroup Value label
1_Race Value label
2_Race Value label
```

What I want is:

```
DepVarLabel
Age Group
1_AgeGroup Value label
2_AgeGroup Value label
Race
1_Race Value label
2_Race Value label
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to deal with the issue is using the `refcat` option.

Here is an example:

```
sysuse auto, clear
xi: logit foreign i.rep78 i.trunk
estout . using example.txt, ///
    refcat(_Irep78_2 "Rep 78 Categories" _Itrunk_6 ///
    "Trunk Categories", nolabel) label replace
```

The output should be closer to what you are looking for. Note the use of `xi:` is necessary here because it allows us to call the factor variables _Ivar_value.